# "Cover" image without knowing the width and the height of the block

Tags: html, css, background, size

Below is my code:

```css
.background{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff') no-repeat center bottom / cover;
}

 #subimage{
    background: url("https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff") no-repeat bottom / cover;

  position: absolute;
  left: 24.5%;
  top: 28.3%;
  width:??
  height: ??
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <div class="background">
                    <div id="subimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
     </header>
 </body>
```

I don’t know the size of the image, so I don’t know the size of the block (if possible, I can use the img tag, but the block is more suitable for my task).
It is necessary to obtain the “native” image size, as the cover does, but without knowing the width and height of the block;

Comment: Can you please add a image of the desired output you want.

Comment: @AwsmeSandy, it's just an iMac in the background. I could create all this in Photoshop (to fix the position and the size of the mac on the background), but I want to use two different layers(div's) (the background and the mac). If you do this with: "width: x px; height: y px; "- nothing flexible, the mac will not be fixed in the position when resizing the screen.

Comment: Fixed relative to the background image*

Answer (score 1):

May be this is helpful to you.
I used background as a base, without giving it any height but did that with padding-bottom. and then smartly put the subimage over it, and yes it is responsive in all the screens

```css
.background{
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 85%;
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/bX8rPqr/mac-computer-screen-png-apple-mac-computer-screen-png-1122.png) no-repeat center bottom / cover;
    background-size: contain;
}

 #subimage{
background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff) no-repeat bottom / cover;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 12;
    width: 92%;
    height: 61.9%;
    left: 4.1%;
    bottom: 28.6%;
}
```

```html
    <header>
            <div class="background">
                    <div id="subimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
     </header>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer) But I need the sub-image to be without height and width) That is, it should get its native size. In my case, I do not know "width: 92%;
height: 61.9%; "and want to use the native size parameters. Because at least it’s difficult to calculate the percentages of sizes from a Photoshop picture all the time.

Comment: For a native size you must have to use <img> tag, a background image never allow its covering div to takes its native size, Actually the background image takes the native size of the div.

Comment: it works, but ...) I've said that for my task I need to work ( to create an animation) in a subview( so I need to create a canvas in the image, but ... we can’t)